# UITableView within a UIView not triggering didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have been searching through the many SO answers for this question and have not found a solution that works, so I thought I'd ask one myself.

I have a normal `UIViewController`, and within in is a `UITableView`. I am populating the table view correctly, but the method

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is not being called. My data source and delegate have both been linked up correctly, I have User Interaction Enabled, and Single Selection is set for the Selection setting.

Could the issue be something with embedding a `UITableView` within a View Controller? How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure you're not using didDeselectRowAtIndexPath ? I made that type lot of times and it's always a pain to spot

Comment: @Signo yea I saw some other people suggesting this fix elsewhere, unfortunately its not my problem :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I was an idiot and put a line within my custom UITableViewCell that said

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Oops :/

Thanks to everyone who tried to fix my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Have you used any gestureRecognizer? if yes then try this code.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    if ((touch.view == tblObj)) 
    {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. Could it be hidden somewhere, or will it be obviously visible in the sidebar that shows my view hierarchy?

Comment: in the view, if you have used any type of gester then it possible. because when you click on tableview cell gester method is called.

Answer (score 0):

have you set your tableview delegate and datasource ?

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableview.dataSource = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

Select your `tableview` from interface builder (i.e. from view controller or storyboard).

Then select `attribute inspector` from `utilities`,

Now make sure below settings are there,

```
 Selection - Single Selection

 Editing  - No Selection during editing (if you are selecting row during editing then change it)

 Show selection on touch checkbox should be checked
```

Under the `view`,

```
 User Interaction Enable must be Checked.
```

Then Select your `tableview cell`

And make sure,

```
 User interaction enable is checked under `view`
```

Then select content view of cell and check that user ineraction enable is checked.

Second thing make sure that user interaction is enable for your rootview (i.e. self.view) and whole view hierarchy comes between self.view and tableView.

And make sure that you have properly set `datasource` and `delegate` to self like,

```
  self.myTableView.delegate = self;
  self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: I have all of the things you mentioned here, but I linked up the delegate and data source with Interface Builder, instead of in the code. Could that cause a problem?

Comment: It should not make problem then also try to set delegate and datasource like i have mentioned in answer.